# How do we sort layout at runtime (android)

Tags: android, xml, animation, layout

I have a list of elements in a Linear Vertical layout, and I would like to sort them by content at runtime 
for example :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#831a24"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="1" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#7b802e"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"

     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="2" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#831a72"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="3" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="@color/BluePetrol"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="4" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#1a837e"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="5" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#83441a"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="6" />
 <TextView
     android:gravity="center"
     android:background="#46831a"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="50dp"
     android:text="7" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I want to sort the list above while running with animation like this for example:
[image]

I was search for a long time a library to do that I and I could not find